# nginx rewrite nice urls with homemade CMS

Tags: nginx, seo, url-rewriting

I have a home-made CMS, serving a site which I inherited. I'm not really familiar with nginx rewrite rules, although I could set up tiny URLs. Here is my relevant part of the configuration:

```
*location / {
        index index.php index.html;
        root /var/www/www.valami.hu;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @seo;
    }
location @seo {
rewrite ^/([a-z]+)$ /index.php?oldal=$1 last;
break;
}*
```

The problem is that the site has a blog which is located on blogspot.com and the stuff from the blog is taken from there. So what I need help with is a rule for this sort of URL:

```
http://www.valami.hu/index.php?oldal=blog&options=2012/01/some-title-here.html
```

So, it would be fine like:

```
http://www.valami.hu/blog/2012/01/some-title-here
```

The most important is the first rule should be work also as it is more frequently used.

Comment: I think it should work with some sort of IF, I mean if the second parameter is missing the first rule should be applied. Else the other which I asked about... :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually trivial. Watch and learn!

```
 location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @site;
 }
 location @site {
    rewrite ^/blog/(.+)$ /index.php?oldal=blog&options=$1 last;
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?oldal=$1 last;
 }
```

The order makes all the difference. You can also do it by removing the `last` flag and redirecting to `/blog` with the options query string parameter explicitely set. No if is needed.

Comment: Well, it might be trivial, but does not work...
So, if I try it with

    http://www.valami.hu/blog/2012/01/some-title-here

it gives me 404 although this format works:

    http://www.valami.hu/index.php?oldal=blog&options=2012/01/some-title-here

Comment: You are putting the location blocks in the right server and removing the old location / block that you had, right? Order matters in nginx.

Comment: Hello!
Yes, location is fine within the configuration. 
    
    location / {
  index index.php index.html;
  root /var/www/www.kettlebelledzes.hu;
  try_files $uri $uri/ @seo;
  }
    location @seo {
    rewrite ^/blog/(.*)$ /?oldal=blog&options=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?oldal=$1 last;
    }

I changed the plus sign to asterisks and it works as it should!!! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

well seems we only have 2 cases, the `/blog` and the non `/blog`, I'd write 2 location blocks

```
location ~ ^/blog/(.*) {
    try_files $uri /index.php?oldal=blog&options=$1;
}
location ~ /(.*) {
    try_files $uri /index.php?oldal=$1;
}
```

I would have used just `/` and `$request_uri` in the second location but that would put a preceeding `/` in `olda1`, if that wouldn't matter with you then i'd prefer that method, cause it doesn't involve regex.
About `index index.php index.html;` and `root /var/www/www.valami.hu;`, it's better if you move them to the server block instead of the location block, if possible of course.